# Symfony2 path to assets in css

Tags: css, symfony, assets

I have following problem:

i try to load pictures with css. But they can't be found.

My css file:

```
.newsMenu {
    background-image: url(../gfx/bannerSeite.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 900px;
}
```

my TwigTemplate which loads css:

```
{% stylesheets 
    'bundles/doublebeatswebsite/css/index.css'
    'bundles/doublebeatswebsite/css/jquery.mCustomScrollbar.css'
    output="bundles/doublebeatswebsite/css/compiled/main.css"
    filter="cssrewrite"
    filter="yui_css"
%}
```

My DirectoryStructure

```
+src
  +DoubleBeats
    +WebsiteBundle
      +Resources
        +public
          +css
            -index.css
            -jquery*.css
+web
  +bundles
    +doublebeatswebsite
      +css
        +compiled
          -main.css
          -main_index.css
          -main_jquery*.css
        -index.css
        -jquery*.css
```

Browser output; Created by cssrewrite

```
url("../../../../../bundles/doublebeatswebsite/gfx/*.png")

Die angegebene URL konnte nicht geladen werden
```

I've allready tried absolute path in the css file what also didn't work (and what i try to avoid)

```
url(/bundles/.../gfx/*.png)
```

I tried also without cssrewrite and with

```
background-image: url(../../gfx/bannerSeite.png);
```

**EDIT**

I just found out that also pictures i've set with {{ asset() }} are not working. It all worked before and I can't figure out what changed. I tried now to set the rights to 777 of all web files. Myabe i changed something by coincidence in the config?! You have any idea?

Comment: filter="cssrewrite,yui_css"

Answer (score 2):

You might try using uglifycss: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/assetic/uglifyjs.html

I ran into trouble trying to use yui_css but had no problem using uglifycss with the instructions above.

Also I believe Yui compressor is being deprecated:

> The YUI Compressor is going through a deprecation process. But don't worry! See How to Minify CSS/JS Files (using UglifyJS and UglifyCSS) for an alternative.

Source: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/assetic/yuicompressor.html

Comment: Thanks! I#m going to check it out and maybe I will switch completly!
But I guess it won't solve my problem as i just found out that also pictures i've set with {{ asset() }} are not working. It all worked before and I can't figure out what changed. I tried now to set the rights to 777 of all web files. Myabe i changed something by coincidence in the config?! You have any idea?

Comment: Hope this isn't stating the obvious, but it could be worth clearing the cache, running the assets:install + assetic:dump again. I've only recently started learning all this myself and similar problems a couple of days ago.

Comment: Yeah i did this all the time. Thanks anyway!

Comment: Oh and if you choose to go with uglifycss, I found it preferable to install to the app/Resources folder directly. (See note under install instructions at the link provided)

Answer (score 0):

Use `Assetic` with `cssrewrite` filter:

http://symfony.com/doc/2.3/cookbook/assetic/asset_management.html#fixing-css-paths-with-the-cssrewrite-filter

Comment: As i wrote: I'm using cssrewrite. You can see it twig.file - code